# Volatile function (can be macro) that allows me to alternate between two values

Tags: excel, volatile

I want to create a "turn" system. I want my spreadsheet to return in one cell, one of the two values I have in a column, but I want it to return in an order

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| TEXT 1 | Return value |
| TEXT 2 |  |

In the return value cell, I want to show TEXT 1, after I have run another macro I want that to change to TEXT 2, and continue to alternate between the two values forever, **i.e return T1, action, return T2, action, return T1, etc.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this simple macro?

```
Sub ChVal()
    If Range("B1") = Range("A1") Then
        Range("B1") = Range("A2")
    Else
        Range("B1") = Range("A1")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it. Thank you, I knew it had to be simple :)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for how to mark resolved, new to stack overflow. Thanks :)

Comment: If you are a regular excel user then keep using stack overflow. You can learn extra ordinary tips and tricks here.